# Debian 7 + django + gunicorn + virtualenv : site-packages egg-link not in pythonpath

Tags: python, django, gunicorn, egg

Context :

- Debian 7
- gunicorn (installed from debian package in order to use /etc/gunicorn.d configuration)
- Project dependencies installed via pip in a virtualenv

Dependencies are installed using pip install -r requirements.txt
In this file we have 3 packages which comes from github repository.

eg.

```
-e git+https://github.com/truc/bidule.git#egg=bidule-master
```

Here my gunicorn.d configuration :

```
CONFIG = {
    'mode': 'django',
    'environment': {
        'PYTHONPATH': '/path/to/my/django/project/:/path/to/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/',
    'PRODUCTION': '1',
     },
    'working_dir': '/path/to/my/django/project/',
    'user': 'user',
    'group': 'group',
    'args': (
        '--bind=127.0.0.1:8090',
        '--workers=3',
        # '--worker-class=egg:gunicorn#sync',
        #'--timeout=30',
    #'--preload',
    'myproject.settings'
    ),
}
```

But the 3 github packages are not in /path/to/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ so modules are not found in path.
I've noticed that there is a file : bidule.egg-link which contain a path to /path/to/virtualenv/src/bidule-master

For the moment the only workaround i found is to add manually path to theses packages in PYTHONPATH in gunicorn.d conf.

```
'PYTHONPATH': '/path/to/my/django/project/:/path/to/virtualenv/src/bidule-master/:/path/to/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/',
```

My question is there is a way to not have to put each github package manually in pythonpath ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the django-specific mode of Gunicorn is deprecated, and doesn't work anymore with Django 1.7.  See https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/705 and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/wsgi/gunicorn/

For your specific problem, instead of tweaking `$PYTHONPATH`, try setting the `'python'` key to the python binary in your virtualenv.  It should work out automatically where the modules are located.

Complete config for Django 1.7:

```
CONFIG = {
    # Default mode is WSGI
    'working_dir': '/path/to/my/django/project/',
    'python': '/path/to/virtualenv/bin/python',
    'user': 'user',
    'group': 'group',
    'args': (
        '--bind=127.0.0.1:8090',
        '--workers=3',
        # '--worker-class=egg:gunicorn#sync',
        #'--timeout=30',
        #'--preload',
        'myproject.wsgi'
    ),
}
```

Comment: Note, it would seem that we should install the python package gunicorn in virtualenv the same version as of the system. Eg for debian squeeze 7: pip install gunicorn == 0.14.5